# Color Wheel in iPad app? Possible?

Tags: ipad, color-wheel

I have seen a few iphone apps with color wheels but i am not sure how they were created for if the source code is available.

I was wondering if anyone has seen a color wheel in an ipad app or ideas on how to go about creating one. If that is not possible purchasing source code is an option for me.

Comment: They must be possible if you've seen them. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [How to draw a color wheel in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108921/how-to-draw-a-color-wheel-in-objective-c/5110332#5110332)