# iOS Objective-C How to draw a colorwheel with only 'warm colors'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, color-space

I have a colorwheel like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735555/5226245

Now I'm trying to draw only the 'warm colors' and replace the whole wheel with only those colors. 
For example:
I want the color's from 45° to 60° and show only those in the wheel.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you any Image ir Screenshot related to this , then add in Que ?

Comment: Na, don't have any image or screenshot. But for an example you can see at this link: http://colorschemedesigner.com/csd-3.5/ the colorspace. And if you go to 45° till 60° you will see the piece of the circle I want to spread over the whole circle.

Answer (score 2):

Since you linked the post with a sample code, I modified it a bit to make it correspond to what you may want to do.

The main idea is that, when you are drawing the wheel using UIBezierPath, you have to provide the very colors you want to draw on screen.
If you look at the code in the link you provided (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735555/5226245), you'll see the following line of code in the `viewDidLoad` method :

```
// ...
// You create a color and then use it to color a small part of the wheel
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1]; 
[color setFill];
// ...
```

This is where you want to tweak the method. 
So ***all you have to do*** **is to provide your own colors** ! Briefly, you have to provide "enough" colors (not 10-20 but more like >100 or 180 as it is in the link), otherwise the gradient of your color wheel will not be smooth.

To do that, there is only one line of code you have to change.

```
    // replace
// UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:((float)i)/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
    // with something like
UIColor *color = [self provideWarmColorSliceForSlice:( i ) slicesCount:(sectors)];
// the variable is then automatically handled further in the sample.
```

The `provideWarmColorSliceForSlice:slicesCount:` method could be defined as follows :

```
- (UIColor *)provideWarmColorSliceForSlice:(NSInteger)sliceNo slicesCount:(NSInteger)totalSlices {
    // I want to cover the interval [200; 255] U [0; 40] which contains the warmest colors
    int warmHueStart = 200;
    int warmHueEnd = 40;
    // If you want the standard color wheel, just use
    // warmHueStart=254; warmHueEnd = 253; // interval [254; 255] U [0; 253]

    // code to compute the hue
    int l = (255-warmHueStart) + warmHueEnd;
    float inputRatio = ((float)sliceNo)/totalSlices;
    float targetedHue = (float) ((warmHueStart + ((int)(inputRatio * l)) ) % 255);
    float hue = targetedHue / 255.0f;

    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0f brightness:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

And voilà ! Nothing more, but more code reuse and you can be happy ( well, if the answer didn't come late : j )

Answer (score 0):

## color picker, May be helpful to you

easy to integrate [VBColorPicker](https://github.com/sakrist/VBColorPicker)

Another One is [RSColorPicker](https://github.com/RSully/RSColorPicker)

A fully scalable, dynamically rendered color wheel for iOS.  [iOS-color-wheel](https://github.com/justinmeiners/iOS-color-wheel)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I have a color-picker. My problem is, how I can spread out only one area of colors. For example the area from orange to red.